# why Python can access CockRoachDB without CA certificate

Tags: python, database, connection, cockroachdb

I don't know why I need to provide CA certificate and account/password to CockroachDB when I access via SSH, but Python only need account/password no need CA certificate? Why is that?

Python APP and CockroachDB are on different LINUX machine.

DB version:
CockroachDB CCL v21.2.14 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

python version:
3.9.13

python package:
sqlalchemy-cockroachdb==1.4.4

I have been searching for a day, but could not find the answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Which parameters are you using with `cockroach start`?

Here are instructions for starting a secure cluster

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.2/secure-a-cluster

and an insecure cluster

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.2/start-a-local-cluster